# How to convert function call chain into a single variardic templatre function call?

Tags: c++, tuples, c++14, variadic-templates

I am given a variardic function like this:

```
template<typename ... PARAMS>
static void processParameters( const PARAMS&... params);
```

I am looking for a simple and efficient solution to wrap variardic function with a stream-like API (function/operator call chain)
similar to this:

```
(ParamList() << a << b << c).call();
or to this
call(ParamList() << a << b << c)
```

so that **call()** would translate to  **processParameters(a,b,c)** 
with possibly minimal overhead on construction/copy-construction/destruction of the parameters.

I attempted to make an implementation which works but it is based on tuples and creates too many copies of the objects due to construction/destruction of the tuples in the chain calls.

```
template<typename A1, typename... ARGS>
struct ParamList
{
        ParamList( const std::tuple<const A1&,const ARGS&...> &&tuple) : args(tuple) {}
        template<typename ARG>
        ParamList<A1,ARGS...,ARG> operator << (const ARG & arg)
        {
                return ParamList<A1,ARGS...,ARG>(std::tuple_cat(args,std::tuple<const ARG&>(arg)));
        }
        void call()
        {
                callProcessor(std::make_index_sequence<sizeof...(ARGS)+1>() );
        }
private:
        template<size_t... ISEQ>
        void callProcessor (std::index_sequence<ISEQ...> )
        {
                processParameters(std::get<ISEQ>(args)...);
        }
        const std::tuple<const A1&,const ARGS&...> args;
};

template<typename A1>
struct ParamList<A1>
{
        ParamList(const A1 & a1) : arg1(a1){}
        template<typename ARG>
        ParamList<A1,ARG> operator << (const ARG & arg)
        {
                return ParamList<A1,ARG>(std::tuple<constA1&,const ARG&>(arg1,arg)));
        }
        void call() { processParameters(arg1); }
private:
        const A1& arg1;
};
template<typename ARG> ParamList<ARG> makeParamList(const ARG &arg)
{
        return ParamList<ARG>(arg);
}
```

Usage:

```
(makeParamList(A()) << B() << C() ).call();
```

Comment: It seems like this is going to be more trouble than it's worth. Can you tell us why you need to re-write the syntax of C++?

Comment: Just use tuple of references throughout. Your use case doesn't require the...thing... to be useful outside the immediate full-expression anyway.

Comment: T.C: tuple of refs makes it slightly better, however tuples themselves are still being copy constructed. I am thinking how to do it without tuples.
Thanks anyway for the idea.

Comment: Edited to reflect recommended change (tuple of refs)

Comment: If your compiler can't optimize away copying tuples of references, file a bug with your compiler vendor.